# How to change particle colour with react-particle-js

Tags: reactjs, particle.js

I'm using [react-particle-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-particles-js) and I can't seem to change the colour of the particles or the link lines, I'm using regular [particle.js](https://vincentgarreau.com/particles.js/) syntax because a lot of it is similar, can't find a solution in the docs either. Here's what I've got so far for the particle config:

```
const particleOpts = {
particles:{
    number:{
        value:150,
        density: {
            enable:true,
            value_area: 1000
        },
        "color": {
            "value": "#005496"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the [website](https://vincentgarreau.com/particles.js/) with an example of the particles you can download the current config.

It says the `color` should be in `particles` not `number` as you have it.

**particlesconfig.json**

```
{
  "particles": {
    "number": {
      "value": 80,
      "density": {
        "enable": true,
        "value_area": 800
      }
    },
    "color": {
      "value": "#0000ff"
    },
    ....
}
```